# How to identify the version of MS-Word on client machine to export report to Word document

Tags: java, javascript, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, jasperserver

I have developed a report using *JasperReports* (*iReport* tool), which needs to be exported to MS-Word document. I have Word-2007 on my machine and it is working fine with *.docx* extension (hardcoded). However if any machine has MS-Word 1997-2003 installed which takes *.doc* version, it will cause problem as I am using harcoded value *.docx*.

Is there any way to handle this?

If knowing the word version on client machine is the only option how can i know the version installed? I think this part of code should be in javascript/jQuery (to know MS-Word version on client machine).

Please let me know how this can be accomplished.

Comment: Why do you assume that someone has Ms-Office at all? To find installed software you'll have to look up the windows registry and it is not possible (thank gods) from javascript.

Comment: If it MUST be export to MS Word, require that your end user have Word 2007. Otherwise, why not also export as ODT and PDF? Then at least your user could read it as PDF, even if they can't edit it in the other formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inspect the contents of somebody's machine from a browser. That would be a severe security risk.

Give them the choice. JasperReports can export in lots of formats; give the user multiple options and, if necessary, add a brief explanation to each option. Alternatively, give the user a .doc file, which the latest versions of MS word and OpenOffice can also open.